# Get list of files name and path in whole google cloud with a particular file extension using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a google cloud bucket which is having the files with the extension `.jtl`, I need to get these file names and paths irrespective of the nesting of folders they are in using NodeJS.

How can we do that!

Answer (score 3):

I think this link might help you

https://cloud.devsite.corp.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

You can try this API, and give the preferred parameters present in that,
for example: in your case you can give delimiter as jtl, and then you can copy the curl command or http or node JS as you prefer and execute this in your google cloud platform

The command will look something like this:

curl 
'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/xyz12345/o?delimiter=jpg&includeTrailingDelimiter=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--compressed

Provide your API key and Access token to be able to run this in your google cloud platform.